# want to put 'play' icon for some of the listview items

Tags: java, android, listview, imageview, textview

[image: **Check the image....This is where I want the Play icon**]so what I want is in my app there are few items which contain a media player so I want to put a 'play' icon on that list view item aligned at the right. The list view item contains an image view and text view(both having item icon and item name).
**is there any way i can insert images to particular items**

here's my code:

first.java:

```
public class first extends AppCompatActivity {
private ListView listView;
private String[] names = {"१. प्रार्थना",
        "२. सुखकर्ता दु:खहर्ता",
        "३. गजानना श्रीगणराया",
        "४. येई हो विठ्ठले",
        "५. लवथवती विक्राळा",
        "६. दुर्गे दुर्घट भारी",
        "७. आरती ज्ञानराजा",
        "८. हे भोळ्या शंकरा",
        "९. ओवाळू आरती",
        "१०. मंगेशा महारूद्रा",
        "११. आला गणराया",
        "१२. शेंदुर लाल चढायो",
        "१३. एकदंता",
        "१४. कर्पूर गौरा",
        "१५. हे गजवधना",
        "१६. प्रथमेश्वरा",
        "१७. जयदेवा हे  साईनाथा",
        "१८. श्री सत्यनारायणाची आरती",
        "१९. श्री महालक्ष्मीची आरती",
        "२०. ॐ जय लक्ष्मी माता",
        "२१. आरती संतोषी माता की",
        "२२. श्री हनुमंताची आरती",
        "२३. सुखंकर्ता की दु:खहर्ता",
        "२४. ॐ जय जगदीश",
        "२५. जय श्री विश्वकर्मा",
        "२६. हे गौरी गजानन",
        "२७. हे गजानना गौरीनंदना",
        "२८. आरती नवदुर्गेची",
        "२९. हे साईनाथा जगदिश्वरा",
        "३०. धन्य धन्य हो प्रदक्षिणा",
        "३१. घालीन लोटांगण"};
private int imageid[] = {R.drawable.prath,
        R.drawable.ganeshaji,
        R.drawable.ganpati,
        R.drawable.vita,
        R.drawable.shivji,
        R.drawable.durgamaa,
        R.drawable.nyan,
        R.drawable.bol,
        R.drawable.krishna,
        R.drawable.mangeshi,
        R.drawable.ala,
        R.drawable.shen,
        R.drawable.ekdant,
        R.drawable.karpur,
        R.drawable.gajavad,
        R.drawable.pratha,
        R.drawable.saibaba,
        R.drawable.satyanarayan,
        R.drawable.laxmimaa,
        R.drawable.omjailak,
        R.drawable.santoshimaa,
        R.drawable.hanuman,
        R.drawable.ganeshaji,
        R.drawable.skd,
        R.drawable.vishwakarma,
        R.drawable.ganpati,
        R.drawable.ganeshaji,
        R.drawable.navdurga,
        R.drawable.saibaba,
        R.drawable.danya,
        R.drawable.gana};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setIcon(R.mipmap.icon);
    final CustomList CustomList = new CustomList(this, names, imageid);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(CustomList);
}
}
```

arti.java:

```
public class arti {
private String names;
private int imageid;
public arti(String names,int imageid){
    this.names=names;
    this.imageid=imageid;
}
public String getNames(){
    return this.names;
}
public int getImageid(){
    return this.imageid;
}
}
```

customlist.java:

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private String[] names;
private int[] imageid;
private Activity context;

public CustomList(Activity context, String[] names, int[] imageid) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_layout,names);
    this.context = context;
    this.names = names;
    this.imageid = imageid;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, null,    true);
    TextView textViewName = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    textViewName.setText(names[position]);
    image.setImageResource(imageid[position]);
    return listViewItem;
    }
```

first.xml:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

listlayout.xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textViewName"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

[image: checkout this image]

I want the play image to be placed after the name of the items

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the image is -1 in your `getView()` method like this:

```
if (imageid[position] != -1) {
    image.setImageResource(imageid[position]);
} else {
    image.setVisibility(View.GONE); //or View.INVISIBLE
}
```

But like this you have to set -1 as id for all items where you don't want an image

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Try making the listlayout relative and use the option as below:

"To Right of" for image view to right of text view
"visibility" to show or hide the music icon. You have to enable the visibility in code as txtView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) as by default it is invisible.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/headerLinearLay"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="80dp"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:textSize="22dp"
       android:text="New Text"
       android:id="@+id/textViewName"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
   <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textViewName"
        android:visibility="invisible" /> <!-- Enable when you want to show the play button -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you add an example to your image where exactly you want the icon for each item.

Comment: check the new image

Answer (score 0):

In your listlayout.xml

```
<Button
android:layout_width="80dp"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:visibility="gone"
android:id="@+id/playButtonView" />

<ImageView
android:layout_width="80dp"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:id="@+id/imageView" />

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:textSize="22dp"
android:text="New Text"
android:id="@+id/textViewName"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Add a view to hold the Play button image. There may be another way to do this that makes more sense for you, but this should give you a good starting point.

In your customlist.java

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, null, true);
    TextView textViewName = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Button playButton = (ImageView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.playButtonView);
    if(playButtonShouldBeVisible) //change to fit your logic
        playButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    textViewName.setText(names[position]);
    image.setImageResource(imageid[position]);
    return listViewItem;
}
```

---

Edit 1:

Addressing the comments below. If you mean that You don't need a button for the play Image (OPTION 1), then simply change

```
<Button
android:layout_width="80dp"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:visibility="gone"
android:id="@+id/playButtonView" />
```

to

```
<Button
android:layout_width="80dp"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:visibility="gone"
android:id="@+id/playImageView" />
```

If by that comment you mean that you mean that you don't need an additional View, the Image View you'd already included was the one you'd use for your play image.(OPTION 2) I would change

```
<Button
android:layout_width="80dp"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:visibility="gone"
android:id="@+id/playButtonView" />

<ImageView
android:layout_width="80dp"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:id="@+id/imageView" />
```

to just

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="80dp"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:visibility="gone"
android:id="@+id/imageView" />
```

these changes would be reflected in customlist.java as either

OPTION 1:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Button playButton = (ImageView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.playButtonView);
if(playButtonShouldBeVisible) //change to fit your logic
    playButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

gets changed to

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
ImageView playImage = (ImageView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.playImageView);
if(playImageShouldBeVisible) //change to fit your logic
    playImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

OPTION 2:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Button playButton = (ImageView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.playButtonView);
if(playButtonShouldBeVisible) //change to fit your logic
    playButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

gets change to

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
if(imageViewShouldBeVisible) //change to fit your logic
    image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

These changes should help indicate define a view in the listlayout.xml that is the play image you might wish to display, then locate that view in your Java code and provide a handle to it, then determine whether that view should be visible and based on that change the visibility property.

Comment: That play image is just to indicate user that this item contains a music file....thats it....

Comment: could you please tell me this part if(playImageShouldBeVisible)

Comment: i want to set the play icon for only few listview items for 3,4,5.....could you please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just do this steps:

**1.** add Button invisible button with your icon to your xml:

```
   `<Button
    android:id="@+id/playButton"
    android:background="your_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:visibility="invisible" />`
```

**2.** in adapter class create Set positions = new HashSet<>() and add positions that you need to this set.

**3.** in getView() method check:

`if(positions.contains(position)){
        Button play = (Button) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.playButton);
        play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}`

use BaseAdapter instead of ArrayAdapter, just extend BaseAdapter and implement it's methods, in getCount() return total number of list items, other methods leave empty.
In getView() do **point 3** written above 
Final code looks like this:

`public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private String[] names;
    private int[] imageid;
    private Activity mContext;
    private Set set;

```
public Adapter(Context context, String[] names, int[] imageid) {
    super(context, R.layout.item);
    mContext = (Activity) context;
    this.names = names;
    this.imageid = imageid;
    fillSet();
}

private void fillSet() {
    set = new HashSet<>();
    set.add(1);
    set.add(2);
    set.add(6);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return names.length;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = mContext.getLayoutInflater();
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv);
    tv.setText(names[i]);
    iv.setImageResource(imageid[i]);
    if (set.contains(i)) {
        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.playButton);
        button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    return view;
}
```

}`

It should make what you want

Comment: I added button in my listlayout.xml.....And in the Customlist.java added this:Set positions = new HashSet<>(1,2,6); and did what you said in the getview()...still no luck.....this is all I have done nothing else....please help!!!!

Comment: doing so causes force crash.....I have a imageView and TextView for the listview....and you have not used inflater for it...please help me with this...try to use my code...Im new to development]

Comment: @Devk could you update your adapter in question, want to see your code